# Forcing xUnit tests to run as a console app

Tags: visual-studio, xunit, windows-console, terminal.gui

My project (Terminal.Gui) makes extensive use of console APIs (it is a 'console GUI framework'). When our unit tests run (either in VS or with `dotnet test`) they run in an environment where the console APIs don't work. For example, the Win32 `GetConsoleMode` API fails on the output handle.

Is there a way to configure xUnit to start the test processes in a console vs. whatever host it runs in by default?